# Tell application - any version shortcuts?

Tags: macos, ms-word, applescript

Running OSS 10.6.8, MacBook pro,
I have 3 versions of msword for Mac.

I would like my script to open a file using " msword for mac 2008 " but i have word 2004 and 2011 also on my laptop. Aside from including the full path in the script, is there a shorthand way to refer specifically to the 2008 version of word? I have heard of 4 letter shorthand codes for apps, but no direct experience. Perhaps each app has a unique code? (Full path is fine just cumbersome because of my folder structure.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the application. Each application resolves the application name differently.

For instance, in Illustrator, if type `tell application "Illustrator CS5"`, when I compile the script, it automatically changes to `tell application "Adobe Illustrator"`, and the script will send events to either the newest version or the version that is currently open.

On the other hand, InDesign allows you to target a specific version. I can type `tell application "InDesign CS5.5"` and it will resolve to `"InDesign CS5.5"`.

I don't have any experience with Word specifically, but here are two options for targeting a specific version.

#### Open the version you want to use

As I stated above, some applications will target the version that is open instead of trying to target the newest version. If I have Illustrator CS6 and Illustrator CS5, Applescript will target CS6 by default. But, if I already have CS5 open, it will target that.

#### Create a variable for the version you want

If your main concern is to save typing, create a variable with the path to the Word version you'd like to use, and use that variable in your `tell` statement.

```
set Word2008 to "path:to:Word.app"
tell application Word2008
    -- do stuff
end tell
```